# Best way to get user's Android Market username

Tags: android, google-play

For licensing purposes, I need to know my users' Android Market account, which *I believe* is the same as the primary account on their device. I can't find a method that does exactly this so instead I query the user's list of google accounts and use the first one:

```
    AccountManager manager = AccountManager.get(context);
    Account[] accounts = manager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
    String account = "";

    if (accounts != null && accounts.length > 0)
        account = accounts[0].name;

    return account;
```

This approach seems to work but my question is: is the first account in the array returned by `AccountManager.getAccountsByType("com.google")` guaranteed to always be the same as their Android Market account, or are there any (non-trivial) exceptions?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: user will still be able to change his primary email, log into android market, so using market account for licensing is not that effective

Comment: also i don't think there is an actual way to confirm weather or not an account is primary

Comment: The only way to change the primary account is to wipe the device so I'm not worried about that. My licensing needs to be reasonably secure but I know no method is perfect.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue, did you come up with a solution? I just need a uid which could be their market account email, but not sure how to enforce it.

Comment: Sorry no, I didn't find a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *used* to be the case that the first com.google account registered on a phone was the primary account, and accordingly the account used by Android Market.

Newer versions of Android have done away with the concept of a primary account, and newer versions of Android Market also support multiple accounts.

In summary, there's no longer any difference between the accounts on a phone. All of them may be in use by Android Market simultaneously, and an app may be owned by any one of those accounts (and possibly even several, if the user has bought the app multiple times).

Comment: Do you know as of what version? Thanks.

Comment: This was changed in Honeycomb (Android 3.0).