# How to retrieve customer's email in In-App Billing transaction?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

The [JSON fields](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_reference.html#billing-intents) that are returned with a PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED intent contain very  useful information, but one piece that I am interested in is not listed: customer's email address.

Is there a way to retrieve it, using In-App Billing API?

If not, is there a way to retrieve some other unique identifier for the customer, so that a transaction can be associated with the customer, not the device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running Android 2.x and up, maybe you can get a way with the [owner's email address](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2556540)?

The downside of this is that it requires `android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS` in the manifest. The more permissions your apps requires, the more likely you are to scare prospective users of your app...

Also note that "owner's email address" might not be the same as "purchase account email address" (especially since [Honeycomb 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7972811/576267))

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling to solve this problem too. So what I've come to is using nonce value. Ideally you should generate nonce on the server side prior to sending IN-APP Billing request from your app, so in this case you can connect nonce value to customer's email.

I understand that it's a little bit clunky so if anyone knows better solution I'd like to see it to.

Comment: Can you elaborate about this `nonce` trick? Pointer to sample code? Thanks +1 for now.

Comment: What I meant is you could prior to sending the data to In-App Billing server you could "remember" that this particular fresh node that you are going to send to In-App Purchase server is "connected" to particular customer's email. It is really difficult to explain in further details. BTW consider watching http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TnSNCXR9fbY video, it's extremely useful and explains some techiques of protection of your in-app purchase processes.